# Keeping my database in sync with third party payment processor (Bluepay)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin.forms, atomic

I'm using Bluepay to process payments for a Xamarin mobile application. When a payment or refund is processed, a request goes out the Bluepay, and Bluepay responds with success or failure. After this, the application sends the transaction information to our database to be stored.

The problem, as you may be able to see, is that the third party payment processor and our database could easily become out of sync if the app crashes before the response is received, or before the database call can be made.

If the DB call fails for some reason, this could probably be detected and the transaction information could be resent, but if the transaction data is never actually received from Bluepay (we crash before the response, or something along those lines), how is it possible to resend something we don't have?

I figured this was a common and solved problem, but I can't seem to find a similar question / answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to log the request as soon as it is made. 
If you don't get any response in a defined timespan, you request the transaction from Bluepay. Now if Bluepay doesn't respond or doesn't know of the transaction, you log a timeout and try to respond to the application with the timeout status. Also your app should have an internal handling for timeouts, for example if the connection breaks.